# Parametrized JUnit 5 test with functional interface as source value

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Can I parameterised a test with functional interfaces as source values?

I am testing a record with multiple fields in this way:

```
@Test
void instantiateWithInvalidName() {
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> Sample.withName(""));
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> Sample.withName(BLANK_STRING));
    thenThrowsNPE(() -> Sample.withName(null));
}

@Test
void instantiateWithInvalidAddress() {
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> Sample.withAddress(""));
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> Sample.withAddress(BLANK_STRING));
    thenThrowsNPE(() -> Sample.withAddress(null));
}    
// ...
    private static NullPointerException thenThrowsNPE(Executable exec) {
    return assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, exec);
}

private static IllegalArgumentException thenThrowsIAE(Executable exec) {
    return assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, exec);
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = { Sample::withName, Sample::withAddress }) 
void instantiateWithInvalidField() {
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> func.apply(""));
    thenThrowsIAE(() -> func.apply(BLANK_STRING));
    thenThrowsNPE(() -> func.apply(null));
}
```

I know I could do it in the other way around by parameters: "", BLANK_STRING, and null. But I would like to do test field by field. I think it is more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try smth like this:

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("provideTestData")
    void instantiateWithInvalidField(Function<String, String> func) {
        thenThrowsIAE(() -> func.apply(""));
        thenThrowsIAE(() -> func.apply(" "));
        thenThrowsNPE(() -> func.apply(null));
    }

    private static Stream<Function<String, String>> provideTestData() {
        return Stream.of(Sample::withAddress, Sample::withName);
    }
```

I don't know, what your `withAddress` and `withName` methods return, I assumed that `String`, therefore I took `String` as second generic in `Function<String, String> func`.